# Can't get anything other than HTTP 202 response from eBay API

Tags: ebay-api

(Also posted this on the eBay Dev Forums, but it has low volume and is very slow)

I'm trying to build my first call to eBay's API. I am using Postman Chrome App, but have also tried the Python Requests library, with the same problem in each.

No matter what I send, I just get back an HTTP 202 code with an empty body, instead of the XML response I am expecting. This happens with either the sandbox or the production endpoint. Doesn't matter if I use correct or incorrect credentials, or a valid or invalid API call name.

Screenshot of building the call in Postman:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally heard back from eBay Support.

The problem is the trailing slash on the endpoint. Any kind of trailing slash will cause a generic 202 response. Removing it fixed the problem.